# How to handle quoted arguments as a single argument?

Tags: c, shell

I am working on making a shell which takes input from stdin.

I am trying to parse **un-nested**, quoted arguments containing matching, single or double quotes. (can be mixed with non-quoted arguments)

I want each quoted string to be treated as a single argument so I can put into an array of arguments. Then I want to try to keep all the arguments in an array.

This is similar to how the C executables take arguments in bash shell.

EX:

```
mypersonalshell> first second "Hello World" fourth
results: [first, second, Hello World, fourth]

mypersonalshell> first second 'Hello World' fourth
results: [first, second, Hello World, fourth]

mypersonalshell> first "Hello ' World"
results: [first, Hello ' World]
```

I am assuming to use a combination of strtok on spaces and quotes but unsuccessful in using that combination properly.

What I have so far

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int cmdNum = 1;
    char *input = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nread;
    printf("mypersonalshell[%d]> ",cmdNum);
    while((nread = getline(&input, &len, stdin)) != -1){
        trim(input);
        if ( strcmp(input, "") == 0){
            continue;
        }
        char *inputArgs[10];
        char *token;
        token = strtok(input, " ");
        while(token != NULL){
            // add to string array and parse here
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
        }
        printf("mypersonalshell[%d]> ",++cmdNum);
    }
    free(input);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since `strtok()` obliterates the delimiters, it is unlikely to be the weapon of choice.  Are you ready to deal with `"arguments in double quotes (\") containing escaped double quotes"`? Also remember that you can write `-DVERSION="macOS 10.14.4 Mojave"` or even `-DVERSION='"macOS 10.14.4 Mojave"'`.

Comment: When you come across a starting quote, you need to scan for the matching close quote according to the appropriate rules — which (in a standard POSIX shell) are different for single quotes and double quotes (because backslashes have no special meaning inside single quotes, but do inside double quotes).

Comment: I am not concerned with escaped characters for now. I only want to cover the base of a un-nested single/double quote.

Comment: Look up `strcspn()` — and `strspn()` and `strpbrk()`.  They're all standard (since C90) functions, so they're available "everywhere".  And they will help you analyze your strings without damaging them.  Even without escaped characters, you'll be able to handle both the 'version' arguments I showed in an earlier comment (the second is a minor variant of your embedded single quote example), where the quotes are not at the start of the string, as well as the ones you mention in your question.  Yes, the opening quote is removed as usual, and the matching close quote.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `int main(int argc, char* argv[]){`  when the parameters to `main()` are not used, then to avoid two warning messages from the compiler about unused parameters, use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `printf("mypersonalshell[%d]> ",++cmdNum);`  The variable: `cmdNum` is initialized to 1 and the value is pre-incremented.  so the first time this statement is executed, it will output: `mypersonalshell[2]>`  Probably not quite what you want

Comment: regarding: `if ( strcmp(input, "") == 0){`  The function: `getline()` includes the trailing `newline`, if any,  in the input, so the resulting string will never be equal to ""